# JQuery Hide element and children

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I am trying to make a FAQ on a website. It works perfectly, however, one answer contains a table, that won't hide when clicked on the question.

How can I adjust my JQuery code to make it disappear when I click on the question?

My code:

```
HTML:
    <section class="faqs sections">
            <h1>Frequently asked Questions</h1>
            <p class="question">question1?  </p>
            <p class="answer">blabla  </p>

            <p class="question">question2?  </p>
            <p class="answer">Bla Bla --> See table:
                <table>
                <tr><td>Info</td><td>Text</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Info</td><td>Text</td></tr>
                </table>
            </p>
    </section>

CSS:
.question {
      color: #009fdb;
      display: block;
      font-size: 12px;
      margin: 15px 0 5px;
      width: 100%;
}

.question:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.answer {
    display: none;
}

JQuery:
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $('.faqs .question').append('<span class="plus">+</span>');

    $('.faqs .question').click(function() {
        $(this).next('p').slideToggle('fast');
        question = $(this);
        if (question.children().hasClass('plus'))
            $(this).find('.plus').replaceWith('<span class="minus">-</span>');
        else
            $(this).find('.minus').replaceWith('<span class="plus">+</span>');
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: use .hide() or .show()  == eg $("#myTableId").hide();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `<table>` is invalid child of `<p>` so it is being moved out of that `<p>` by the browser

You can see this for yourself when you inspect the live html in browser dev tools element inspector

Use `<div>` as parent instead

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qh8dj2o9/)**</kbd>

Comment: Did not know this. It works perfectly when I changed the <p> to <div>. Thank you!